# How can I send and receive data to and from a URL, i.e. server side scripts, web services in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

How can I send data (eg, a string or integer value) to a server-side script or a web service through my android application.
Can you please give me some details on how to call web services.or how to get response from web services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http post will get it done.  http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html

This would be the best way to get data from your app to a webserver.  If you are retrieving data a GET request should be performed, not unlike how javascript performs an ajax request.

Here is also a link to a tutorial which may help you understand it a little better http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-http-with-asynctask-example/